# Can I connect to a BLE device and broadcast an iBeacon at the same time?

Tags: swift, bluetooth, core-location, ibeacon, core-bluetooth

I am using an iPad as an iBeacon with CoreLocation. Is it possible to have the iPad connect to another BLE device (non iBeacon) using CoreBluetooth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes.**  An iOS Bluetooth "Central" can connect to a Bluetooth LE Peripheral, and at the very same time act as a Bluetooth "Peripheral" and advertise an iBeacon packet.  CoreBluetooth supports both modes simultaneously.

I have built several apps that do exactly this.

The only trick is that to advertise, the app must be in the foreground with the screen on.